# Movie about boy pulled into medieval ages

Tags: story-identification, movie

Okay I've got one for you that I cannot remember many details for. It is a movie where there is a boy in his room during the 1980s- 1990s time frame. He somehow finds an opening to another dimension/time where there is a knight in armor on a horse. He is pulled into this other dimension/time where he falls onto some hay or something in the middle of a market place and it looks like medieval England. That's about all I can remember. The doorway to the other dimension was in the closet I think or it may have been under the bed, that I am not sure of. I also think the Knight on the horse was bad. 
You guys are awesome if you can figure this one out, I'd love to watch it again.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Kid_in_King_Arthur%27s_Court ? (I think Time Bandits fits better though because of the bedroom aspect)

Comment: It kind of sounds like you've mixed Time Bandits with A Kid In King Arthur's court - elements of both fit, but neither on their own.

Answer (score 11):

"[Time Bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bandits)"(1981)?

From Wikipedia's plot synopsis:

> Eleven-year-old Kevin has a vivid imagination and is fascinated by history, particularly ancient Greece; his parents ignore his activities, having become more obsessed with buying the latest household gadgets to keep up with their neighbours. One night, as Kevin is sleeping, an armoured knight on a horse bursts out of his wardrobe. Kevin is scared and hides as the knight rides off into a forest setting where once his bedroom wall was; when Kevin looks back out, the room is back to normal and he finds one of his photos on the wall similar to the forest he saw. The next night he prepares a satchel with supplies and a Polaroid camera but is surprised when six dwarves spill out of the wardrobe. Kevin quickly learns the group has stolen a large, worn map and is looking for an exit from his room before they are discovered. They find that the bedroom wall can be pushed, revealing a long hallway. Kevin is hesitant to join until the visage of a menacing head – the Supreme Being – appears behind them, demanding the return of the map. Kevin and the dwarves fall into an empty void at the end of the hallway.